# How does play console create mapping.txt file from bundle?

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have an app on the play store and what I observe is that when I upload an app bundle (.aab) file, the play console automatically generates mapping.txt file.

Strange things about this is that the mapping.txt file is more than twice the size of the original bundles. The bundle uploaded is proguarded and obfuscated. How does play console generate mapping file in this case?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ReTracing mapping file is included inside the AAB, so Play Console only has to extract it.

As to why the file is much larger than the AAB itself, one possibility is that it compresses very well because it's text, so even though it takes 60MB uncompressed, it possibly compresses to only a 10MB or so compressed.

You can inspect the content of the AAB and see the size of the files in Android Studio using the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer) -- the name is a bit misleading since it also supports AAB.

Comment: Thank you Pierre.
I can see in the APK analyser that under BUNDLE-METADATA, there is proguard.map file which is around 4.5MB.
Guess this has all the meta data in compressed format to generate ReTracing mapping file.

Comment: This _is_ the ReTracing mapping file.